# Boostrap and Html - why is one input box full width and the others so short?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Why is one input box full width and the others so short?  This is my html.  I am using bootstrap:

```
                <form action="https://www.example.net/auth/create_user" class="form-horizontal" id="login-attempts-form-admin method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">        
                     <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">   

                        <!-- id -->
                        <div class="form-group">     
                            <label for="id">
                                Reference Id
                            </label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="id" value="" id="id" style="" class="form-control" placeholder="" disabled="disabled"  />
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-info"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- end input group -->
                            <span class="help-block">
                                The Reference Id is created automatically.
                            </span>
                        </div> <!-- end form-group Id -->


                        <!-- ip_address -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ip_address">
                                IP Address
                            </label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="ip_address" value="" id="ip_address" style="max-width:none !important" class="form-control input-xlarge" placeholder=""  />
                            </div> <!-- end input group --> 
                        </div> <!-- end form-group ip_address -->

                        <!-- login -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="login">
                                Login
                            </label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="login" value="" id="login" style="" class="form-control" placeholder=""  />
                            </div> <!-- end input group -->
                        </div> <!-- end form-group login -->
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end of row -->        
                </div> <!-- end of container. -->

                </form>
```

I even tried to make the ip_address field wider by stating style="max-width:none !important" but no use.  Is there any way to make the fields wider?  Is there a preset width in bootstrap?  I was of the belief the default was max width.

This is what my final output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I tested the code I didn't see any different widths with the inputs.

On ip_address field, I am using style="max-width:none !important"... Any CSS you add will not work with the inline style max-width:none; !important.

It will override any changes you are making in the CSS file or any where else. Inline styles especially !important will override any attached style sheets or classes.

I think the problem may be you have this on your input `style="max-width:none !important"`It is overriding the default bootstrap setting and not setting your input to max width.

That's if you want them wider, shorter wrap in a `<div>` then manipulate the `<div>` with CSS or the "col-sm-6" etc.. classes.

Example from Bootstrap website version 4. Also, version 3 has the "form-control" class as well. It makes your form 100% width then you can manipulate it by wrapping in a `<div>` of your choice or another suitable element or CSS.

EXAMPLE:

```
    <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Comment: I do have 'form-control' in my inputs.  Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem may be you have this on your input style="max-width:none !important"It is overriding the default bootstrap setting and not setting your input to max width.

Comment: On ip_address field, I am using style="max-width:none !important"... Any CSS you add will not work with the inline style max-width:none; !important. It will override any changes you are making in the CSS file or any where else. Inline styles especially !important will override any attached style sheets or classes.

Answer (score 0):

Low rep to add as a comment, but trying your code end up with same length input fields. So don't see a problem from my end. 
One thing maybe the version of bootstrap you are using, as I used the latest from the Bootstrap page (4.1.3), as older versions might have some changes within the CSS.
You could add your CSS which would give a better view if you are not changing something.
Another thing is to try:

```
input {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: On ip_address field, I am using style="max-width:none !important".  I also tried your below but does not work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested the input field lengths weren't different.
But if it happens try styling the input tag with

```
    <input style="max-width: 100%">
```

or add this to css